# d3.js animate/transition circles on update

Tags: javascript, animation, d3.js, transition

I have a simple line graph that checks every 5 seconds for updates & redraws the line/scale if needed. This all works well EXCEPT: the data-point dots.

What am I missing in the redraw to move the dots? The dots are there when the graph is first rendered. But on update, they don't move when the line gets redrawn. So I selected a new data source on update, and the old data-points remained fixed.

Redraw on update

```
var svgAnimate = d3.select("#animateLine").transition();

        svgAnimate.select(".line") // change the line
            .duration(750)
            .attr("d", valueline(data));
        svgAnimate.selectAll(".circle") // change the circle
            .duration(750)
            .attr("d", valueline(data));
        svgAnimate.select(".x.axis") // change the  x axis
            .duration(750)
            .call(xAxis);
        svgAnimate.select(".y.axis") // change the y axis
            .duration(750)
            .call(yAxis);
```

Initial drawing:

```
svgAnimate.selectAll("dot")
        .data(data)
    .enter().append("circle")
        .attr("class", "circle")
        .attr("r", 5)
        .style("fill", function(d) { 
            if (d.close <= 400) {return "red"} 
            else { return "black" }
        ;})
        .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.date); })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.close); })
```

This is what I don't want.
[image]

Comment: Can you setup a jsFiddle?

Comment: @ChrisJamesC : Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UZpHZ/4/). Although, I can't get my data source to update properly in it. On my local machine, I was using a csv as a source type. Thought I made the necessary changes for it to work.

Comment: Ya. I knew there was an issue. Not sure why the data isn't populating. Feel free to edit it. I put some sample data in. Maybe I'm not passing the array correctly.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that the function `valueLine` is the function you use to draw the line. Thus, when calling it again with a new data you redraw the line.

For the circles the attribute `d` has no sense. However, if we consider that the `y` axis does not change, then you can do something like:

```
svgAnimate.selectAll(".circle") // change the circle
    .data(newData)
    .duration(750)
    .attr("cx", function(d){return x(d.date)};
```

If you need to change the `y` coordinates, then you have to modify the `cy` attribute of the circle.

My code might not be as rigorous as necessary, please post a jsFiddle if you still have problems.

Comment: The Y axis does change in my example actually. Applying what you have done actually doesn't change the output at all. And why wouldn't ValueLine work for this selection? It works in the previous lines when I'm changing the line?

Comment: `ValueLine` draws a **line** between the input points it gets, it won't help to draw circles. If the yAxis changes, then do the same for the yAxis.

Answer (score 0):

I had some issues with updating circles in charts too. 
Here is a working fiddle and might some people for future searches if they have the same problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/noo8k17n/

The problem is this line:

```
var svgAnimate = d3.select("#animateLine").transition();
```

It needs to be removed and then in the update method you can add and remove circles.